# php mktime() unexpected result

Tags: php, mktime

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,31,3,2018));
?>
```

Demo https://3v4l.org/CPmvm

Output: 2020-07-03 instead of 2018-03-31

How can i get this resolved?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `unexpected input === unexpected result` :) .You have the month and day transposed. You did read the manual didn't you? http://php.net/mktime . Sometimes these things are easily missed. https://3v4l.org/FbIbg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,3,31,2018));
```

---

You have passed 31 months and 3 days to `mktime()`. Which should add another 2 years to 2018. that's why it returns 2020.

**Correct Syntax :**

```
mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst);
```

Source - [PHP mktime() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_mktime.asp)